# unit test example on angular.io

Tags: angular, unit-testing

in [document](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#dashboard-standalone)

```
  it('should raise selected event when clicked', () => {
    let selectedHero: Hero;
    comp.selected.subscribe((hero: Hero) => selectedHero = hero);

    heroEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    expect(selectedHero).toBe(expectedHero);
  });
```

Shouldn't it be like

```
comp.selected.subscribe((hero: Hero) => {
  selectedHero = hero;
  expect(selectedHero).toBe(expectedHero);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be like this because of `jasmine`.

If you do:

```
it('should raise selected event when clicked', () => {
    let selectedHero: Hero;
    comp.selected.subscribe((hero: Hero) => {
      selectedHero = hero;
      expect(selectedHero).toBe(expectedHero);
    });

    heroEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
});
```

And, because of a bug, the event `click` is not caught, then your expectation will never be tested, and you don't have a failure.

By testing `selectedHero` after the `click`, the tests ensures that if the click event is not handled, the test will fail because `selectedHero` will be `undefined`.

Comment: ok, but shouldn't it run expect right after click and then `selectedHero = hero;` ?

Comment: Your error is an IDE warning I think, you can fix this by adding `= null;` at `selectedHero` declaration. The expectation is after the event trigger because the `subscribe` does not actually trigger the event, it's here to receive data when this event gets triggered. Which is what is done using `heroEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null);` once the sobscription is created.

Comment: yeah, I figured that one too. Error was cause by `strictNullChecks`. But the part I don't get it is when we run the code, if we run expect first, how can we get `selectedHero = hero`. Shouldn't it be async ? Let's say there is a debounceTime in event handler in component for 500. It will always run expect first then run ` selectedHero = hero;`

Comment: No because the `subscribe` call is equivalent to "When selected will emit something, set it in my selectedHero variable", it's not an actual assignment.

Comment: I think it is an actual assignment. I just tested it with debounceTime set as 500. I need to wrap it with fakeAsync and use tick(500), so the expect will run correctly.